# Can I somewhere see my reject votes?

Tags: support

Sometimes when I voted to reject an edit and it still needs more vote than my vote, then I'm sometimes interested if others agree with me. An example is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904518/adobe-air-and-different-os-filesystems). Is there any possibility for me to see the questions I have voted on edits? And see how others have voted? I couldn't find something like that. And are there statistics available how many edits I voted and accept/reject rate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can click on your "Activity" tab in your profile and then filter on "reviews" to see all suggested *and* rejected, but I don't think there's a way to see only rejected

If you want to see your total rejected/accepted, you can click on any individual edit suggestion you've acted on and it displays those as well.

For example, by clicking on [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/31729) I can see as of now:

> Roflcoptr approved 30 edit suggestions, and rejected 2 edit suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. This seems what I was looking for. Do you know if there is a badge which depends on reviewed edits?

Comment: @Roflcoptr - no badge, but you do get +2 points per edit up to a maximum of 2,000 points.

Comment: @ChrisF but only if I'm below a certain threshold if I understood it correctly.

Comment: @Roflcoptr - well yes. More than 2,000 rep and you can make edits to **posts** without needing approval, but you still can gain rep from suggesting edits to tag wikis (excerpts and bodies are treated as separate posts too)>